# ORDER BY works only with column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

So, I have this query

```
SELECT
    NOTES,
    DATECREATED,
    DATEMODIFIED,
    * 
FROM myTable
WHERE
    USERCREATEDBY = 465
    AND NOTES LIKE ' :%'
ORDER BY DATECREATED
```

and it throws this error `Ambiguous column name 'DATECREATED'`.

I see nothing wrong with my query and I found a fix for this in the form of adding an alias to column `DATECREATED`, like `DATECREATED a`, and ordering by alias, `ORDER BY a`.

I do not understand why this happens and I am very curious to know why.

Comment: Well, if your table contains this column `DATECREATED`, then you're selecting this column **twice** with the above `SELECT` - once explicitly, once implicitly by using the `*`. Don't do that!

Comment: In addition to everything said in all the answers and comments - you can also use `ORDER BY` with numbers - position of column in select list. In your example - `ORDER BY 2` would give you ordering by 2nd column - `DATECREATED`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your table contains this column `DATECREATED`, then you're selecting this column **twice** with the above `SELECT` - once explicitly, once implicitly by using the `*`.

So your result set now contains **two columns** called `DATECREATED` - which one do you want `ORDER BY` to be applied to??

Either explicitly specify the complete column list that you need, or then at least provide an alias for the `DATECREATED` column:

```
SELECT
    NOTES,
    SecondDateCreated = DATECREATED,
    DATEMODIFIED,
    * 
FROM myTable
WHERE
    USERCREATEDBY = 465
    AND NOTES LIKE ' :%'
ORDER BY DATECREATED
```

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because you're selecting DATECREATED twice, once as a column and once in *

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
  USERCREATEDBY = 465
  AND NOTES LIKE ' :%'
ORDER BY DATECREATED
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 3):

Because `DATECREATED` appears in the `SELECT` list twice.

In this case both instances refer to the same underlying column but it is still invalid syntax. In general you could have two projected columns with the same name that refer to different columns.

```
SELECT
    DATECREATED AS D,
    DATEMODIFIED AS D
FROM myTable
ORDER BY D /*Obviously ambiguous*/
```

By the way applying any sort of expression to the `ORDER BY DATECREATED` resolves the ambiguity as it will then be resolved against the column in the base table.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
NOTES VARCHAR(50),
DATECREATED DATETIME,
DATEMODIFIED DATETIME
)


SELECT
    NOTES,
    DATECREATED,
    DATEMODIFIED,
    * 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY DATECREATED + 0 /*Works fine*/
```

I just mention this in passing however. It is definitely not a suggestion that you should do this.

Comment: This answer is so cool! Never really thought about adding a `0` to the column in `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

It seems `ORDER BY` can't understand which `DATECREATED` column should be used for ordering. You specified it twice in `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
    NOTES,
    DATECREATED,
    DATEMODIFIED,
    * 
FROM myTable
WHERE
    USERCREATEDBY = 465
    AND NOTES LIKE ' :%'
ORDER BY 2
```